# PyMongo: Match, Group, and Sum Aggregation returning 0 as a Sum

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find the total number of twitter followers for a specific political party in my users collection. A document in my users collection has the following schema:

```
{
    "Name": "Jimmy Gomez",
    "Chamber": "house",
    "Party": "D",
    "State": "CA",
    "Twitter Screen Name": "JimmyGomezCA",
    "Twitter Id": "398193180",
    "Number of Followers": 18213 (This is an Int32)
}
```

Right now my pipeline's first stage is getting all documents with a specific party and then the second stage is grouping them and having a `Total Number of Followers` field where it is summing up the `Number of Followers` field found on the original document.

When I try and run the aggregation I am getting a single `doc` (Which makes sense since I am matching one political party) with the `Total Number of Followers` being 0.

This is my pipeline (PyMongo):

```
    total_follower_count_pipeline = [{'$match': {'Party': 'D'}},
                                    {'$group':{
                                        '_id':None,
                                        'Total Number of Followers': {
                                            '$sum':'Number of Followers'
                                        }
                                    }}]
```

Am I using the wrong aggregation method for this current scenario, or are my pipeline stages incorrect?

Comment: missing $ reference in `$sum: "$Number of Followers"`

Comment: Thanks that was the issue,